# Matrix lie algebra automorphisms

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Can all matrix Lie algebra automorphisms be expressed as

$A \rightarrow R^{-1} A R$ for some invertible $R$?

By this, I mean taking all linear transformations between a vector space and itself, and mapping each to another linear transformation (also between that same vector space and itself) such that the commutator is preserved.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865062/non-inner-automorphism-of-lie-algebras).

Comment: It occurred to me that one can interpret your question more broadly than I did in my answer. For that more general version, see this MO question and answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/149363/27465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether for a matrix Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, all automorphisms are inner automorphisms. The answer is no in general. E.g. for $n \ge 3$, the map

$$X \mapsto -X^{t}$$

(negative of the transpose) is an automorphism on the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb C)$ and $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)$ which is not given by conjugation with a matrix. (Fun exercise: For $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, it is still an automorphism but an inner one, i.e. it is induced by conjugation with a certain matrix.)

In general, the automorphisms of simple (split) Lie algebras are pretty well understood. The existence of outer automorphisms can be read of the Dynkin diagram, and they exist in types $A_{n\ge 2}, D_{n \ge 3}$ and $E_6$. For a discussion see https://mathoverflow.net/q/14735/27465 and ch. VIII §5 of Bourbaki's *Lie Groups and Algebras*.

For other types of Lie algebras which might be represented as matrices (e.g. solvable ones, and even non-split semisimple ones over arbitrary fields), I have no idea, but I guess the answer is still "no" in general.

Comment: It seems that this sort of transformation usually is done in physics with the unitary operation being the parity operator. Why does it work in that case or, in other words, not work in this case?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What exact transformation is applied to which exact Lie algebra in that other "case"?